# FFImageLoading Xamarin iOS imagePath

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ffimageloading

I am using Xamarin.iOS and saving images with FFImageLoading. I would like to get the path where the image is saved.

In the code below `information.FilePath` is `null`:

```
return ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(imageUrl).
    WithCache(CacheType.All).
    Success((information, result) =>
    {
        image.ImagePath = information.FilePath;
    }).Retry(3, 5000);
```

Does anyone know where to get the image path?

Comment: Did the imageUrl start with http or https?

Comment: Maybe it is only stored in memory at this point of time. You've specified CacheType.All

Comment: Using the Simple.iOS.Sample in FFImageLoading's GitHub repo. If I use your code the FilePath is not null, so I'm assuming it may be an issue with how you are setting this up or the URL. Are you able to show a bit more code?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT https.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I try to use all of cache types and I have the same problem